# Implementation of class based Tower of Hanoi with stacks solution error

Tags: python, class

As a beginner to OOP, I would appreciate some guidance on how to implement the following solution. I would like it to print a solution for the towers of Hanoi in the way that my other solution does (e.g. move from pole 1 to pole 3, etc)

**The implementation/desired output I would like is as shown below:**

```
Enter the height (no. of discs) in your tower:3

=For a tower of height: 3 ....here is the solution======

Move disc from First Pole to Last Pole
Move disc from First Pole to Second Pole
Move disc from Last Pole to Second Pole
Move disc from First Pole to Last Pole
Move disc from Second Pole to First Pole
Move disc from Second Pole to Last Pole
Move disc from First Pole to Last Pole

...and you're done!
```

I'm obviously happy for the variables to either refer to First Pole, Second Pole, or just A, B,C for ease of coding.

**Current Code**

```
class TowerOfHanoi:
     def __init__(self, numDisks):
         self.numDisks = numDisks
         self.towers = [Stack(), Stack(), Stack()]
         for i in range(n, -1, -1):
             towers[0].push(i);

     def moveDisk(src, dest):
         towers[dest].push(towers[src].pop())

     def moveTower(n, src, spare, dest):
        if n == 0:
            moveDisk(src, dest)
        else:
            moveTower(n-1, src,dest, spare)
            moveDisk(src, dest)

tower=TowerOfHanoi(3)
tower.moveTower(3,"A","B","C")
```

Stack Class Code (although I think this is wrong and doesn't quite fit in?)

```
class Stack:
     def __init__(self):
         self.items = []

     def isEmpty(self):
         return self.items == []

     def push(self, item):
         self.items.append(item)

     def pop(self):
         return self.items.pop()

     def peek(self):
         return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

     def size(self):
         return len(self.items)
```

**Error**

```
self.towers = [Stack(), Stack(), Stack()]
   NameError: name 'Stack' is not defined
```

Accepted/Desired answer:

For an accept on an answer, could you please
1. Comment your solution or provide an explanation for what is happening in the stack part 
2. Provide the implementation (creating an object based on the class that works) and a solution that displays the output as shown below.

****************************UPDATE*******************************:**

I also tried this, I don't really understand how it all fits together, and that is why the explanation is needed. ...it also comes up with an error

```
class TowerOfHanoi:
     def __init__(self, numDisks):
         self.numDisks = numDisks
         self.towers = [Stack(), Stack(), Stack()]
         for i in range(n, -1, -1):
             towers[0].push(i);

     def moveDisk(src, dest):
         towers[dest].push(towers[src].pop())

     def moveTower(n, src, spare, dest):
        if n == 0:
            moveDisk(src, dest)
        else:
            moveTower(n-1, src,dest, spare)
            moveDisk(src, dest)

class Stack:
     def __init__(self):
         self.items = []

     def isEmpty(self):
         return self.items == []

     def push(self, item):
         self.items.append(item)

     def pop(self):
         return self.items.pop()

     def peek(self):
         return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

     def size(self):
         return len(self.items)

n=int(input("Enter n"))
tower=TowerOfHanoi(3)
tower.moveTower(3,"A","B","C")
```

**error**

```
 for i in range(n, -1, -1):
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

Comment: It looks like you just put in calls to `Stack()` as stubs, and you're hoping someone will fill in the rest for you?  The error isn't of much interest, since it appears to be expected.  But understand that SO is not a code writing service.  You need to post your best attempt at a solution, then ask a *specific* question about what you're having trouble with.

Comment: Please post your `Stack` class code as well.

Comment: I have a Stack class implemented as follows - updating code

Comment: You need to import `Stack`.  Given the error you show, it isn't picking it up.

Comment: BTW, you can just use `self.items[-1]` to access the last element.

Comment: Also note that `range(n, -1, -1)` includes `n` through `0`, i.e. `n+1` items total.  Is that your intent?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a Tower of Hanoi solver or will the user have to determine the movements? If you want us to give you a ToH solver this is not a code writting service, if you wanted to implement the game you were quite close.

Comment: I'm trying to simply implement the game. I just need that little extra guidance. Also, I want an answer that uses my original code, not something completely different (I could also just get that off the internet or google!)

Answer (score 1):

Bug correction with minimum modifications:

```
class TowerOfHanoi:
     def __init__(self, numDisks, src, spare, dest):
         self.numDisks = numDisks
         self.towers = {
                        src: Stack(),
                        spare: Stack(),
                        dest: Stack()
                       }
         for i in range(n, 0, -1):
             self.towers[src].push(i);

     def moveDisk(self, src, dest):
         self.towers[dest].push(self.towers[src].pop())
         print("{} --> {}".format(src, dest))

     def moveTower(self, n, src, spare, dest):
        if n >= 1:
            self.moveTower(n-1, src, dest, spare)
            self.moveDisk(src, dest)
            self.moveTower(n-1, spare, src, dest)

class Stack:
     def __init__(self):
         self.items = []

     def isEmpty(self):
         return len(self) == 0

     def push(self, item):
         self.items.append(item)

     def pop(self):
         if not self.isEmpty():
             return self.items.pop()
         else:
             raise IndexError("pop from empty Stack")

     def peek(self):
         return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

     def __len__(self):
         return len(self.items)

n = int(input("Enter n: "))
tower = TowerOfHanoi(n, "A", "B", "C")
tower.moveTower(n, "A", "B", "C")
```

First of all if you want to give the Stacks a name you need to use a `dict` not a list. I also added a `print`to the `moveDisk` function, quite a bunch of `self`s that you were missing and corrected the algorithm you were using.

Answer (score 0):

The following code offers a Tower of Hanoi class representing a board where you can determine the number of Pegs and Disks. The Pegs are then accesible from the origin, destiny and aux attributes, the last of them being a list with the remaining Pegs (by default it uses 3 but can be any number). The board only offers a move method. Two examples can be found at the end, with 3 disks 3 pegs and 4 disks 4 pegs respectively. The Pegs enforce the items to be placed in the right order and only allows to extract items when there are some to extract.

```
class Disk:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Disk size={}>".format(self.size)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if hasattr(other, 'size'):
            return self.size == other.size
        return NotImplemented

    def __ne__(self, other):
        if hasattr(other, 'size'):
            return self.size != other.size
        return NotImplemented

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if hasattr(other, 'size'):
            return self.size < other.size
        return NotImplemented

    def __le__(self, other):
        if hasattr(other, 'size'):
            return self.size <= other.size
        return NotImplemented

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if hasattr(other, 'size'):
            return self.size > other.size
        return NotImplemented

    def __ge__(self, other):
        if hasattr(other, 'size'):
            return self.size >= other.size
        return NotImplemented


class Peg:
    def __init__(self, _id):
        self.id = _id
        self.__items = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Peg {} {}>".format(self.id, self.__items)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__items)

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self) == 0

    def fits(self, item):
        if self.is_empty():
            return True
        return self.__items[-1] > item

    def push(self, item):
        if self.fits(item):
            self.__items.append(item)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Item {} doesn't fit in peg {}".format(item, self.id))

    def pop(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            return self.__items.pop()
        else:
            raise ValueError("Peg {} does not have any item.".format(self.id))

    def peek(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            return self.__items[-1]
        else:
            raise ValueError("Peg {} does not have any item.".format(self.id))

class TowerOfHanoi:
    def __init__(self, disks=3, pegs=3):
        self.origin = Peg('origin')
        self.destiny = Peg('destiny')
        self.aux = [Peg('aux{}'.format(i)) for i in range(1, pegs-1)]
        for i in range(disks, 0, -1):
            self.origin.push(Disk(i))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<ToH from={} to={} by={}>".format(self.origin, self.destiny, self.aux)

    def move(self, frm, to):
        to.push(frm.pop())
        print("Moved {} from {} to {}.".format(to.peek(), frm.id, to.id))



tower = TowerOfHanoi()

tower.move(tower.origin,  tower.destiny)
tower.move(tower.origin,  tower.aux[0])
tower.move(tower.destiny, tower.aux[0])
tower.move(tower.origin,  tower.destiny)
tower.move(tower.aux[0],  tower.origin)
tower.move(tower.aux[0],  tower.destiny)
tower.move(tower.origin,  tower.destiny)

print(tower)


tower_4_4 = TowerOfHanoi(4, 4)

tower_4_4.move(tower_4_4.origin,  tower_4_4.destiny)
tower_4_4.move(tower_4_4.origin,  tower_4_4.aux[0])
tower_4_4.move(tower_4_4.destiny, tower_4_4.aux[0])
tower_4_4.move(tower_4_4.origin,  tower_4_4.aux[1])
tower_4_4.move(tower_4_4.origin,  tower_4_4.destiny)
tower_4_4.move(tower_4_4.aux[1],  tower_4_4.destiny)
tower_4_4.move(tower_4_4.aux[0],  tower_4_4.aux[1])
tower_4_4.move(tower_4_4.aux[0],  tower_4_4.destiny)
tower_4_4.move(tower_4_4.aux[1],  tower_4_4.destiny)

print(tower_4_4)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I want an answer/fix to my original code posted, not just a whole new solution, as otherwise there are plenty of solutions I can just google and cut and paste. thanks in advance

Comment: The key is also the use of stacks. so that needs to be in the solution for teaching purposes

Comment: My `Peg` class is your stack with some additional checks. It verifies that the inserted items are in order for example.